# Как получить значение на первый день каждого месяца в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица такого типа:

| time | vol |
| --- | --- |
| 1652918400 | 272331.8 |
| 1652832000 | 54849419.5 |
| 1652745600 | 29800101.2 |
| 1652659200 | 25920194.9 |

И так далее. По факту, на каждый день одного и того же времени у меня есть определенное значение.
Помогите пожалуйста сделать такой запрос, который будет мне выдавать все значения за 1-ый день каждого месяца с начала "истории" по 1 день текущего месяца. Для наглядности вот вид финального результата:

| time | vol |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 272331.8 |
| 2022-02-01 | 54849419.5 |
| 2022-03-01 | 29800101.2 |
| 2022-04-01 | 25920194.9 |

Как перевести из unix времени в обычный формат я знаю, а вот дальше проблема.
Я в SQL только начинающий, так что буду признателен за любую помощь)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать маску и оператор LIKE. Запрос будет таким `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date LIKE '____-__-01';`, где символ _ означает любой одиночный символ.

Смотрите в тренажёре:
https://www.mycompiler.io/view/IJzRtE0mVFD

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал работать с датой как с датой, а не как со строкой - это более правильно с точки зрения производительности(для компа число сравнить проще чем строку) и семантики(так нагляднее для человека):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DAY(date) = 1;
```